# Localized xUnit.net Output in Visual Studio Output Window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xunit.net

I am using xUnit.net (1.5, but 1.1 seems to have the same issue) in a Visual Studio 2008 solution (with a simple post build event). The host system (Windows XP) is the localized german version and vs2008 is the english version.

The VS output window shows the localized german output like this:

```
1) IXmlSerializableTest.XmlSerializerTest.FactName : Assert.False() Failure
Stack Trace:
   bei Xunit.Assert.False(Boolean condition)
   bei IXmlSerializableTest.XmlSerializerTest.FactName() in D:\svn_checkout\OpenCVConfigurationTool\src\IXmlSerializableTest\XmlSerializerTest.cs:Zeile 86.
```

However, (no surprise) VS is not able to extract the file / line number from the localized output. As a result, VS won't jump to the according fail position when i double click the output line.

Any ideas how to work around this, so I don't have to navigate manually each time? Thanks in advance,
Johannes

Comment: We fixed this for English, but we don't have the resources (or, really, the capability) to cover all Visual Studio languages. :( Sorry!

Comment: I totally understand not supporting any language. In my particular case, the default english output would be fine, but I get the german one (since my OS is german). I think there are unit test frameworks out there supporting customized output, at least by editing the sources and compiling your own binaries. Since the sources are freely available, this might be an option (?). However, as the co-author of xUnit.net, do you think this can be done within a reasonable amount of time? Or are these parts of the code to sophisticated and/or filthy for anyone without detailed knowledge of the code?